# making a new react component want to add code not DOM

Tags: reactjs

I'm relearning react, I've done tons and tons of angular I ran the following command :

```
generate-react component carousel
```

(I'm using [generate-react-cli](https://github.com/arminbro/generate-react-cli#readme))

this works well and generates the following .tsx file (plus test, lazy-loading and style files, which I am omitting) :

```
import React from 'react';
import styles from './carousel.module.scss';

const carousel: React.FC = () => (
  <div className={styles.carousel}>
    carousel Component
  </div>
);

export default carousel;
```

this loads fine in my app but now I want to add actual code, functions.

I can't seem to do this.

I've broken open this const like so :

```
const carousel: React.FC = () => {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }

    componentDidMount() {

    }

    return (
        <div className={styles.carousel}>
            carousel Component
        </div>
    );
}
```

I assume this is where the constructor and so on go,

however in this area the `constructor` name and ect. is not allowed.

so I tried changing the type to React.Component

however at that point I get an error directly on the const name stating :

> TS2740: Type '() => Element' is missing the following properties from
>   type 'Component{}, {}, any>': context, setState, forceUpdate, render,
>   and 3 more.

I'm really shooting in the dark here and reacts docs are antithetical to examples. they refuse to help with any of this.

I want this newer, shorthand syntax but I also want to be able to use lifecycles and functions.

Comment: Functional components don't have/use constructors or lifecycle functions of class-based components. You should definitely spend some time in the react docs about [hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-intro.html), which largely allow for duplication of class-based behaviors like state and effects (side effects of state/props updating).

Comment: You'll have to re-write your component as class-based component if you want constructor and life-cycle methods

Comment: thanks, by class-based do both of you mean `React.Component {....` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out the correc syntax for this is as follows :

```
class carousel extends React.Component {
    componentDidMount() {
        console.log('hello');
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className={styles.carousel}>
                carousel Component
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```